# Mantain values >=0 in colum of nested list in data.table R

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have the following `data.table` object:

```
USER    active  rate   day    # of elements by hour
4q7C0o  1         1.48  1       c(-10, 0, 0, 0, -5, -5, 5, 98, 167, 211, 246)
2BrKY63 1         0.5   3       c(-11, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 5, 15, 24, 89, 187) 
3drUy6I 1         2.58  5       c(-20, 0, -9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 112, 265, 309) 
G5ALtO  1         1.1   7       c(-183, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 20, 153, 170)
```

I would like to keep only the elements >= 0 in each of the lists in column `# of elements by hour`, in order to get something like this:

```
USER    active  rate   day    # of elements by hour
4q7C0o  1         1.48  1       c( 0, 0, 0, 5, 98, 167, 211, 246)
2BrKY63 1         0.5   3       c( 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 15, 24, 89, 187) 
3drUy6I 1         2.58  5       c( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 112, 265, 309) 
G5ALtO  1         1.1   7       c( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 20, 153, 170)
```

I tried the following approach but it is taking too long and when I use a smaller amount of data it gives some strange results :

```
DT[, # of elements by hour[which(unlist(# of elements by hour) >= 0)], day ]
```

Any suggestion in what am I doing wrong? or a better approach to do it faster?

Comment: Can you share data using `dput` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, it is taking a long time, but when I stopped it apparently it is taking each numer as Long (ex. 98L) and not as double precision. I don't kow if that is caussing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(data.table)
dt[, elements_by_hour := lapply(elements_by_hour, function(x) x[x >= 0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dt %>%
   mutate(elements_by_hour = keep(elements_by_hour, ~ .x > 0))
```

Or

```
dt %>%
   mutate(elements_by_hour = map(elements_by_hour, ~ .x[.x > 0]))
```